# Local Volume Folder: Transliterate path, but keep name as is

Tags: assets, control-panel, subfolder

Intention: create a local `Asset Volume` with a bunch of subfolders and files in it and display a file tree on frontend.

All OK, but since the website is in German, I have to do `'convertFilenamesToAscii' => true` but this setting also affects folder names. So all the non-Latin letters are transliterated and we can not use it in the front-end.

I see that `models/VolumeFolder` has got `$name` and `$path` properties and in theory it looks like it would be possible to transliterate `$path`, but keep `$name` as is. In the real world, though, as I see it, I would have to extend quite some core classes to make it work.

Maybe someone has got a better idea how to keep folder names with all the non-Latin chars and use ASCII paths?

Comment: Or maybe I should just turn the ascii conversion off? I'm used to keeping things safe, but when google says it's OK, then maybe I should not worry? https://searchengineland.com/google-using-non-english-urls-non-english-websites-fine-294758

Comment: But still, even with `convertFilenamesToAscii = false`, there's a problem with special characters (I'd need at least spaces in names).